# Filter path that have been already traversed

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

```
Given a query 
    gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(out()).times(2).emit().path()
    ==>[v[1],v[3]]
    ==>[v[1],v[2]]
    ==>[v[1],v[4]]
    ==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
    ==>[v[1],v[4],v[3]]
```

Here we use emit which will emit all result at each loop.In the response we have [v[1],v[4]] and [v[1],v[4],v[5]]. I do not want [v[1],v[4]] in my response as i already [v[1],v[4],v[5]] through which i know that there is a path between V[1] and v[4]. Is there a way to filter the paths that so that i do not have traversed paths ?

Comment: i have tried g.V(1).repeat(out()).times(2).emit().filter(__.not(out())).path() which gives me desired result but it takes more time. Is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The longer paths are, obviously, the last paths being found. The query to get you all non-cyclic longest paths is:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(out().simplePath()).
                  until(__.not(out().simplePath())).
                path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[3]]
```

For a fixed depth of 2 it would be:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(out().simplePath()).
                  emit(__.not(out().simplePath())).
                  times(2).
                path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[1],v[4],v[3]]
```